# Parsing XML data which makes heavy use of identifiers

Tags: haskell, hxt

I am using HXT library with Haskell and
I have an XML file which I want to parse, but it has a lot of cross-references. For example, there is a portion:

```
<object id="..">
  <net id="123">
    ...
  </net>
  <instance id="452" name="abc" />
  <instance id="453" name="cds" />
</object>
```

I want to parse the `net` part into some non-XmlTree term (for example, `State [Int] Int`) and then I want to be able to make use of that term when parsing the `instance` part.

Is it possible to do that, preferably without jumping into managing the state?

Will the problem be solvable if I am to allow `instance` to reference  the `net` object directly, e.g.:

```
<instance id="452" ofObj="123" />
```

?